# Failing to import python modules only on specific user

Tags: python, libraries

I've been trying to figure out this for ages.

When I run certain python programs they would crash saying that certain module can't be imported, while it's actually installed and should be importable.
For example:

- `pip3` would crash with `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler`
- `python2 speedtest-cli` with `ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead`
- `python3 speedtest-cli` with `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'`
- `virtualenv -p python3 myenv` with `OSError: Command /home/myuser/myenv/bin/python3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1`

What's bizarre, is that if I run those programs with `sudo` or even as a new common user they would work just fine. It's happens only for that specific user.

I tried clearing `.cache`, `.pip` and `.python-eggs` in home directory, running `chmod a+rx -R /usr/` comparing all python executable with `which` with working users, but nothing helps. python `sys.path` list is also identical.

Machine is - Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64.

**UPDATE:**

I think I fixed it... No idea how though. I've done everything I've listed in this question and rebooted the machine.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

I learned what caused it. I had `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver"`in my `.bashrc`. Could someone explain please though, why would this happen?

There are no results if I do `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But if I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver"` it breaks some python imports.

Comment: "`/home/grisevg/lolo3/bin/python3`". Sounds like you have a custom version of python in that user's home directory.

Comment: @Patrick that's what `virtualenv` does.

Comment: Does /usr/lib/plexmediaserver contain an installation of Python or Python libraries? That would be my suspicion.

Comment: @slm it has `libssl.so.1.0.0` which could explain problems loading `HTTPSHandler` and `HTTPSConnection`. Also `libexpat.so.1` which would explain problems importing `expat`. So what happens is - instead of loading latest libs from `/usr/lib/`, programs load outdated/different libs from plex folder and hence crash? Nothing really to do with python.

Comment: If you're running an app you could `strace app` and see what libraries it's picking up from this directory to really nail it.

Comment: @slm yep, `open("/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/libexpat.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7` thank you very much [= i learned something today

Comment: @grisevg - nice. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

I had `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/plexmediaserver"` in my `.bashrc`.

`/usr/lib/plexmediaserver` had lots of dynamic libs, including `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libexpat.so.1`. So they were loaded instead of ones from `/usr/lib` and were causing problems. This problem has nothing to do with python actually, it would equally cause problems for any other program that would relay on those libs.

@slm suggested a good way to debug such cases using `strace`.
I my case I did `strace speedtest 2>&1 | grep expat | less` and found proof of wrong library being loaded - `open("/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/libexpat.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7`.

I've seen many people on internet posting similar questions with no solutions at all. 
So hopefully this will help someone.